# can anyone explain what's happening here How its printing world ? @javascript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

```js
const num = () => console.log("Hello") || "world!";

let result = num();

console.log(result);
```

output:

```
Hello
world
```

Comment: console.log returned none, so num returns 'world' so thats why ur code prints hello world

Comment: `console.log` always returns `undefined` so `||` will then evaluate the right side, which is "world".